# Forwarding all TCP to another Host with Specific Port 6900

Tags: linux, iptables, port-forwarding

Hi I tried using this command

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 6901 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.12.77
iptables -I FORWARD -m state -d 0.0.0.0/0 --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

restarted iptables and but the other host is not receiving the request.

I have 2 Host/VPS one is just acting like a proxy and other is the master. Is there something wrong to what I did?

Comment: see redir, it does what you want with TCP.

Comment: Redir? @RuiFRibeiro

Comment: Won't that DNAT all packets to port 6901, including those already DNAT-ed? That'd be a tight little loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect traffic to port 6900. You should write rule like this

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.12.77:6900
```

If you mean to redirect traffic with dport 6900, then your rule is right.

Maybe you didn't enable forwarding from sysctl

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
```